# COUNTIF Cell Color is XXX & Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VB that allows me to COUNTIF based on a cells color;

```
Function COUNTIFCOLOR(rSample As Range, rArea As Range) As Long
Dim rAreaCell As Range
Dim lMatchColor As Long
Dim lCounter As Long

lMatchColor = rSample.Interior.Color
For Each rAreaCell In rArea
    If rAreaCell.Interior.Color = lMatchColor Then
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    End If
Next rAreaCell
CountColorIf = lCounter
End Function
```

To use this you would simply say

```
=COUNTIFCOLOR(A5,J2:J15)
```

With A5 being a cell to reference this color too, and J2:J15 being the range to count on.

This works, however if the cell has been formatted via Conditional Formatting it does not include this in the returned count.

Now I'm stuck =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property, which can read the color of conditional formats. 
Unfortunately it cannot be used in UDFs but only in subs. 
Workaround:
Create an event procedure listening to worksheet change containing the following command:
Target.interior.color=Target.DisplayFormat.interior.color. This will copy the conditional interior color to the interior color.

Add the command Application.volatile to the beginning of your existing function to get it executed when the sheet recalculates.

Here's the required event procedure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Applicaiton.calculate is required as your function takes effect in the next calculation cycle after the color copy.
You may want to limit the effective target range to the required arrea in order to save resources.